# My PC restarts 3 times then I get 3 beeps

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, motherboard

I had a problem with my PC 2 days ago ,in these 2 days I tried many methods to fix it but with no luck.

It happened after shutting down  my PC and unplugged my video  card which is RX 470 to re add thermal paste. After doing it , I reinstalled the video card. Then the PC started  and  then restart after 2 seconds. It did this 3 times then 3 short slow beeps.

A red light is on on the Asrock h87 motherboard. The board has 2 bios 1 and 2 with a jumper to a recover.

I tried unplugging the video card again and tried without video card out but I've got the same 3 beeps and restarts.

I have 3 RAM cards which were working great a second before plugging out the video card ,but I pulled them all and cleaned them and tried one by one with no luck. Same beeps and restarts. I tried the BIOS 2 but I have got the same thing with the red light too. I tried to clear the CMOS  with no luck.  I replaced  CMOS battery but still same.  I tried another power supply which did not work. Last thing is to reseat the CPU and clean the pins. It was good with no bent pins. I tried the built in video card

Comment: 3 short or long beeps in ASRock boards means memory problem.

Comment: You have caused some damage, but have touched too many parts. I suggest to see a professional.

Comment: Thank you sir ,very pity not that easy to find a pro where i live